# Why does the BFS algorithm use a queue?

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm looking at the pseudo-code on Wikipedia

```
Breadth-First-Search(Graph, root):
 2 
 3     for each node n in Graph:            
 4         n.distance = INFINITY        
 5         n.parent = NIL
 6 
 7     create empty queue Q      
 8 
 9     root.distance = 0
10     Q.enqueue(root)                      
11 
12     while Q is not empty:        
13     
14         current = Q.dequeue()
15     
16         for each node n that is adjacent to current:
17             if n.distance == INFINITY:
18                 n.distance = current.distance + 1
19                 n.parent = current
20                 Q.enqueue(n)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

and what I'm curious about is whether there's a specific reason why a queueu is used to hold the nodes. It seems to me that one could use any container since the order of going through the elements currently in the container is irrelevant.

Comment: Hint: the order isn't irrelevant if it's a BFS. Replace it with a stack and guess what happens.

Comment: Another hint: consider what happens if you use queue or stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue is not only a container at all. It's exactly the key idea for this algorithm.

Queue is 
1. a container for sure.
2. It can be only add/pop by certain sequence(queue and stack are both has this attribute)

The second point is the key point to answer your question.

If you are using the queue as a general list, add and pop element directly via index of list, whole algorithm can't be so simple. (that is the queue no longer a queue)

Answer (score 0):

1. Because you don't know the size of the frontier in advance, use queue is more memory efficient.
2. Queue data structures are considered inherently “fair”. The FIFO concept that underlies a Queue will ensure that those things that were discovered first will be explored first.